# How do I properly create my own terminal in mac?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm trying to create my own terminal in mac. So far I've create a hello.terminal file and I opened a terminal and ran the code:

```
chmod u+x /Users/.../Desktop/code.terminal
```

Now when I go to run my terminal that is saved on my desktop it gives me this

```
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

And I'm unable to type anything after it. Also to be more specific, I want my own terminal window to pop up. The code.terminal file is saved on my desktop and it opens but I can't do anything with it because of the message I get above. Any help would be great, Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [this will give you some ideas](https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/)

Comment: No, this doesn't show how u can create your own terminal window. I have a .terminal file on my desktop and when double clicked it opens up a terminal like i want it to but I can't write anything in it....it just gives me the message i stated in my original question

Comment: Are you saying you want to create your very own bash shell application, such as Terminal or iTerm?

Comment: Yes, so basically I created code in C to run and when u run it, it is its very own terminal but now i want to make a new terminal screen pop up when I run it, but I want this terminal screen to be separate from the built in terminal in mac....meaning i can open both terminals at once if i wanted to

Answer (score 1):

A `.terminal` file is a script file that is executed by the Mac OS Terminal when it's double-clicked. Since the file you have created is empty, it doesn't do anything.

A `.terminal` file is not an application, nor can it be turned into one.

If you actually want to write your own terminal application, you will need to use Xcode and learn Objective-C or Swift. This is a much larger task than I can possibly explain here, but you may want to take a look at [fvterm](https://github.com/duskwuff/fvterm), a terminal I wrote some years ago. Keep in mind that it is not finished, and is missing some important features. (If you're interested in extending it, contact me privately -- my email address is in my profile -- and I'll point out some particular areas to take a look at.)

If you just want to open more than one terminal window at a time, you don't need to write your own application. Press Cmd+N in Terminal to open a second window, or Cmd+T to open a tab.